# Can't load files that has xmlns attribute in the first child with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am new to XDocument but I have been looking around for a solution to this problem which I couldn't get to fix.

I need to load some kind of XML files (PNML) that comes this way:

```
<pnml xmlns="http://www.pnml.org/version-2009/grammar/pnml">
 <net id="id" type ="http://www.pnml.org/version-2009/grammar/ptnet">
  ..........</net> </pnml>
```

And I couldn't get to load these kind of files unless I add `"xmlns"` as an Attribute to the node `net` . 
Meanwhile, the files I create myself has this `xmlns` attribute, and I can load them without problems.
While, files that are generated from some other software that I need to be able to use from my software doesn't has this "xmlns" attribute, and if I add it myself to the files generated by this software, I can load those files.

Here's the code I am using to Load :

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(file);
            XNamespace ns = @"http://www.pnml.org/version-2009/grammar/pnml";

            foreach (XElement element in doc.Element(ns + "pnml")
                                .Elements("net").Elements("page").Elements("place"))
            { // Do my loading to "place" nodes for example }
```

But whenever I try to load a file, it just skips my "foreach" statement, and if I add some line before "foreach" like:

```
string id= (string) doc.Element(ns + "pnml")
                                .Element("net").Attribute("id");
```

it says:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here's an example of a file generated by my code and also can be read from my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<pnml xmlns="http://www.pnml.org/version-2009/grammar/pnml">
  <net id="netid" type="http://www.pnml.org/version-2009/grammar/ptnet" xmlns="">
    nodes and information </net> </pnml>
```

NOTE: I use this code to save my files:

```
            XNamespace ns = @"http://www.pnml.org/version-2009/grammar/pnml";
            XDocument doc = new XDocument
            (
              new XElement(ns+"pnml"
                , new XElement("net",new XAttribute("id", net_id), ...));
```

I found a way to save my files without this "xmlns" attribute, but once I omit it, I can't load it from my code. And the first example I wrote is the standard format and I really need to get ride of the "xmlns" problem.

EDIT: I'm sorry if you got confused, what I want is to be able to load the standard PNML files that doesn't have thise "xmlns" attribute within the "net" node.

Comment: Which version of xml and code is not working?

Comment: @DarkKnight the standard one, the one that hasn't the "xmlns" attribute in the "net" node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're missing is that element namespaces are *inherited from their parents*.

So your XML:

```
<pnml xmlns="http://www.pnml.org/version-2009/grammar/pnml">
    <net id="id" type ="http://www.pnml.org/version-2009/grammar/ptnet">
...
```

Contains two elements.  One is `pnml` with the namespace `http://www.pnml.org/version-2009/grammar/pnml`, and the child is `net` *which also has the namespace* `http://www.pnml.org/version-2009/grammar/pnml`.

With this in mind, your query on the existing XML should be:

```
doc.Element(ns + "pnml").Elements(ns + "net")...
```

And your code to generate the XML should be:

```
new XElement(ns + "pnml",
    new XElement(ns + "net", new XAttribute("id", net_id), ...));
```

Comment: This works, I added `ns+"node"` for every node, not just "pnml" and "net", and it is working great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var result = doc.Element(ns + "pnml").Descendants().Where(x=>x.Name.LocalName=="net")
```